# Einstein-Hilbert Action for (+,-,-) metric signature in 1+2 dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action

The correct Einstein-Hilbert action for the metric signature (+,-,-) is,

- $S=1/2k\int R\sqrt{g}d^3x$

or

- $S=1/2k\int R\sqrt{-g}d^3x$

just like in the (-,+,+)?

As you can see I'm interested in the $\sqrt{-g}$ part, does it change signs or does it stay the same for both instances?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Both need the minus. You want a positive quantity inside the square root and in 1+3 dimensions you'll need a minus to fix this.

Comment: Thank you I meant it at 1+2 dimensions, sorry I need to fix it, what about then? @secavara

Comment: The thing under the square root is always $\sqrt{ |\det g|}$. You can fix your sign accordingly.

Comment: Great so $\sqrt{g}$ in this case to make it positive, right? @Prahar

Comment: In $(+,-,-)$ signature, $\det g > 0$ so there's no sign and in the $(-,+,+)$ signature, $\det g < 0$ so there needs to be a sign.